# String to Char Array using a for loop string[0] is always null

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

```
procedure TfmCypher.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
 MasterkeyArray: array of char;
 Masterkey : string;
 j : integer;
begin
Masterkey := edtKey.text;
setlength(MasterKeyArray, length(edtkey.text));

for i:= 0 to length(masterkey) do
begin
 MasterkeyArray[i] := masterkey[i];
end;
```

In the above code, I am trying to figure out why MasterKeyArray fills as { #0, a, b}
MasterKeyArray is always #0. Ultimately I just want a charArray of my string masterkey. I kept having issues with masterkey[0] being assigned #0.   Masterkey string is collected from an editbox.text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings are 1-indexed, but arrays are 0-indexed.  Your loop is trying to access string index 0, which is not valid, and you are exceeding the upper bound of the array as well.

Try this instead:

```
procedure TfmCypher.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  MasterkeyArray: array of Char;
  Masterkey : string;
begin
  Masterkey := edtKey.text;
  SetLength(MasterKeyArray, Length(Masterkey));

  for I := 1 to Length(MasterKey) do
  begin
    MasterkeyArray[I-1] := Masterkey[I];
  end;
end;
```

A simplier solution is to get rid of the loop altogether and use `Move()` instead:

```
procedure TfmCypher.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: integer;
  MasterkeyArray: array of Char;
  Masterkey : string;
begin
  Masterkey := edtKey.text;
  SetLength(MasterKeyArray, Length(Masterkey));
  if Masterkey <> '' then begin
    Move(Masterkey[1], MasterKeyArray[0], Length(Masterkey) * SizeOf(Char));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome thank you! can you tell me a bit more about why this is the case with strings?

Comment: @user1868232: Backward compatibility. Pascal strings (`ShortString`, or `String[255]`) stored their length in byte 0, and the first character of the string in byte 1. When long strings were introduced in Delphi 2, they remained 1-based for compatibility with older code and have stayed that way ever since.

Comment: Until XE3, that is, when the `{$ZEROBASEDSTRINGS}` directive was added to optionally enable 0-based string indexing. It is OFF by default, but may be turned ON in the future when the new mobile environment is ready.